# Miss granularity of uop-cache

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

Intel Optimization Manual/`B.5.7.3`

> There are no partial hits in the Decoded ICache. If any micro-op that
>   is part of that lookup on the 32-byte chunk is missing, a Decoded
>   ICache miss occurs on all micro-ops for that transaction

Does the uop-cache miss occur really on 32-byte granularity?

Answer (score 5):

**On `KbL i7-8550U` it behaves like there is no partial hits per cache line, not a 32 bytes region**.

I actually ran much more different experiments then described below, but it is not possible to fit them all here.

---

Intel Optimization Manual documents that uop cache is L1i inclusive:

> The Decoded ICache is virtually included in the Instruction cache and
>   ITLB.

Consider the following

**Example 1.**

```
;edi = 1 << 31
align 32
test_uop_cache_hit:
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 

    ;More 8 * nop ax blocks

    dec edi
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit
    ret
```

Collecting the counters `icache_64b.iftag_hit`, `idq.dsb_uops`, `idq.mite_uops` we have the following plot

[image]

The uops plot is reasonable. All the uops are delivered from dsb.

The first plot shows that there is only one tag lookup per L1i cache line which is 64 bytes in size. Tag lookup is necessary in order to find a uop cache entry.

**Example 2.**

Adding jmp in the middle of 8 * `nop ax` blocks of the same cache line.

```
;edi = 1 << 31
align 64
test_uop_cache_hit:
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    jmp test_uop_cache_hit_1

align 32
test_uop_cache_hit_1:
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 
    nop ax 

    dec edi
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit
    ret
```

We have the following plots:

[image]

The uop plot is reasonable again. From the `icache_64b.iftag_hit` I came to the conclusion that branches predicted to be taken cause li1 tag lookup in order to find a corresponding entry into the uop cache (even if branch source and target belong to the same line). With this observation the `Intel Optimization Manual/2.5.5.2`

> Once micro-ops are delivered from the legacy pipeline, fetching
>   micro-ops from the Decoded ICache can resume only after the next
>   branch micro-op.

looks pretty reasonable to me.

Now consider a bit more interesting

**Example 3.**

I will use assembly pseudo-code to save space

```
align 64
test_uop_cache_hit:
     8 * nop ax

    19 * nop
    jmp test_uop_cache_hit_1  
align 32:
test_uop_cache_hit_1: ;new line starts here
;more 8 * nop ax 19 * nop jmp blocks
    dec edi
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit
    ret
```

We have the following results

[image]
[image]

What's interesting here is that even in spite of taken branch micro-op inserted and `8 * nop ax` fits the uop cache perfectly **they are not delivered from the uop cache**. As can be seen on the plots **the only micro-op delivered from the uop cache was macro fused `dec-jnz`**.

The result made me thing that if some 32-byte region is not fit the uop-cache the whole cache line is marked as not contained in the uop cache and next time any 32-byte part of it is asked it will be delivered from the Legacy Decoded Pipeline.

Is branch micro-op necessary to switch from Legacy Decoded Pipeline? To check it consider

**Example 4.**

```
align 32
test_uop_cache_hit:
    32 * nop
test_uop_cache_hit_0: ;new line start here
    16 * nop ax
    ;more 16 * nop ax
    dec edi          ;new line start here
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit
    ret
```

Here is the result for dsb

[image]

It is clear that all of the uops were delivered from the legacy decoded pipeline.

---

Consider a bit more complex examples to check if the assumption made under the `Example 3.` works there:

**I.**

```
align 32
test_uop_cache_hit:
    6 * nop ax
    test edi, 0x1
    ;ends 64 byte region, misses due to erratum
    ;does not matter for the example
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit_1

    32 * nop
test_uop_cache_hit_1:
    dec edi
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit
    ret
```

The results are

```
 1 075 981 881       idq.dsb_uops
50 341 922 587       idq.mite_uops
```

The results are perfectly reasonable. When the branch is not taken and `32 * nop`s are delivered it is clear that they cannot fit the uop cache. After the `32 * nop` the macro fused `dec-jnz` is delivered from the Legacy Decode Pipeline. It fits the uop cache and therefore next time when the branch is taken it will be delivered from dsb.

**The result is very close to what is expected: `(1 << 31)/2 = 1073741824`**

**II.**

More complex example then previous

```
align 32
test_uop_cache_hit:
    test edi, 0x1
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit_2
    jmp test_uop_cache_hit_1

;starts new cache line
align 32
test_uop_cache_hit_1:
    8 * nop ax
; 32 byte aligned
test_uop_cache_hit_2:
    6 * nop ax
    nop dword [eax + 1 * eax + 0x1]
    ;End of 32 bytes region
    ;misses due to erratum
    ;Important here
    jmp test_uop_cache_hit_3
test_uop_cache_hit_3:
    dec edi
    jnz test_uop_cache_hit
    ret
```

Here is the result:

```
 5 385 033 285      idq.dsb_uops
25 815 684 426      idq.mite_uops
```

The result is expected. Every time the  `dec edi - jnz test_uop_cache_hit_2` is taken it jumps to the 32-byte region containing the `jmp` at the end of it. So it will miss the dsb. Next time the `dec edi - jnz test_uop_cache_hit_2` is not taken the `jmp test_uop_cache_hit_1` is taken. Normally it would hit the dsb since `8 * nop ax` fits it perfectly, but remember that on the previous loop iteration the `jmp` at the end of 32 byte region caused miss. They both belong to the same cache line and therefore dsb miss occurs every iteration.

**The result is every close to what is expected: `(1 << 31) + (1 << 31)/2 + (1 << 31) = 5368709120`**.

**Removing just one `nop ax` from the 32-byte region with `jmp` at the end while preserving `test_uop_cache_hit_3` 32-byte aligned causes all the uops to be delivered from dsb:**

```
29 081 868 658       idq.dsb_uops
     8 887 726      idq.mite_uops
```

**Note:** If there 2 branches predicted to be taken per cache line the results turned out to be very unpredictable so it is difficult to give a reasonable estimation. It is not clear to me why.

Comment: If you're using NASM / YASM, you can write `times 19  nop` to repeat an instruction X times.  (Most often used with pseudo-instructions like `db 0` or some pattern, but works with any single instruction.)